# Do we have treegrid in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I wanna TreeGrid kind of component in RCP or any alternative to TreeTable component?
Since TreeTable is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add TreeColumn items to the standard SWT Tree component to give you multiple columns. That should give you what you want.

Comment: It doesn't works for me since <br/> I want to show tree in tabular format. On tree Items I want to apply the mouse down listener. On mouse down I want to select that particular Item. And want to have its co-ordinates.

Comment: You can set it to allow selection of the entire row, but I don't think there's any way of selecting individual cells.

Comment: Thank you Nick for the kind reply. I guess I need to think the solution in different way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) widgets.  The Grid widget may fit your needs.